# .NET 4.5 Databinding to Singleton using ObjectDataProvider (used to work in .NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, singleton, .net-4.5

First, I have to say that all this already worked flawlessly on .NET 4.0!

Now switching to .NET 4.5 (or even .NET 4.0 with installed .NET 4.5), at ListBox.DataContext I get an *XamlParseException.InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException "Binding.StaticSource cannot be set while using Binding.Source"*

I implemented a NavigationController as singleton, providing some data to a list.
The singleton instance is provided via an ObjectDataProvider representing the *Instance* property of the singleton.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.WPF.Reuse.Navigation.NavigationView"
             xmlns:n="clr-namespace:UI.WPF.Reuse.Navigation"
             ...>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="NavigationController" ObjectInstance="{x:Static Member=n:NavigationController.Instance}" />
    ...
  </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- On property DataContext: InvalidOperationException "Binding.StaticSource cannot be set while using Binding.Source" -->
    <ListBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource NavigationController}, Path=(n:NavigationController.CurrentViewModel)}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(n:NavigationViewModel.SubScreens)}"
             ...
    >

    ...
```

So, what would be the appropriate construct to bind to a property of a singleton in .NET 4.5?
My experiments did not work out so far...